# integrating nodejs, socket.io and express on laravel application on production environment

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

We have existing laravel application running on VPS provider on ubuntu with apache, we have to implement real-time features through node app (socket.io and express) seems fine in local environment but when i try it to production it doesnt working at all, my question is, what is the proper configuration i will be made in order to run my node app like `$ node server.js`

**snippet code(server.js).**

```
var socket  = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen(server);
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3001;


server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});



io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   code here....
});
```

**snippet code(client-side(js-file)).**

```
var socket = io();
```

**ERROR**

`GET https://hostname/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1480917572919-5 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: our app is not served by AWS

Answer (score 0):

snippet code(client-side(js-file)).

```
var socket = io() ;
```

to

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a good idea to add explanation to your answer rather than just the code change.